# Confidence Band using ciplot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to draw a confidence band in MATLAB using the ciplot function

The code as follows:

```
Y=Y(:,1); % 5139 by 1 vector
pd = fitdist(Y,'Normal');
ci = paramci(pd);% gives a 2 by 2 matrix of lower, upper for my(:,1) and sigma(:,2)
%ciplot(lower, upper,x, colour)
ciplot(ci(1,1),ci(2,1),Y);
```

I get the following error

```
Error using fill
Vectors must be the same length.

Error in ciplot (line 36)

fill([x fliplr(x)],[upper fliplr(lower)],colour)

Error in GHVDConfidenceInterval (line 12)
ciplot(lower,upper,Y);
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `ciplot` is the function from  [Mathworks' FileExchange](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/63314-ciplot-lower-upper-x-colour-alpha-). In this case, the function expects the same length of vectors for lower, upper and x. I think this is what you are looking for:

```
Y = randn(5139,1);

pd = fitdist(Y,'Normal');
ci = paramci(pd);
plot(Y);
hold on;
ciplot([ci(1,1) , ci(1,1)] , [ci(2,1) , ci(2,1)] , [1 length(Y)]);
```

Comment: Sorry. I don't get a confidence band. I just get a straight line cutting though the middle of the curve. at 0.

Comment: It's not a straight line, it is a very thin band. You have a lot of points so the confidence interval of the mean is very thin! Try the same with `Y = randn(30,1);`

Comment: Hi friend. I wanted my curve to be within the band, as regular. The line cutting through the curve is not helping. Maybe index generation would help. Can I help me out with that?

Comment: I think you should first clarify what band you want to plot, from a statistical point of view. In this question you asked for the confidence interval of the mean, and this is what it looks like! Please start a new question.